# flutter CachedNetworkImage doesn't work as expected

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to work with cached images.
I followed this https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images,
but it doesn't work.

CachedNetworkImage throws error: "The argument type 'CircularProgressIndicator' can't be assigned to the parameter type '(BuildContext, String) → Widget'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [hello2] lib/main.dart:21)"

Below is the problem code:

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final title = 'Cached Images';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CachedNetworkImage(
            placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            imageUrl:
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```dart
````

Comment: What Flutter version are you using? (`flutter --version`)

Comment: flutter --version
Flutter 1.2.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 8661d8aecd (5 weeks ago) • 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
Engine • revision 3757390fa4
Tools • Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

Comment: I'd try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted

Comment: Tried link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted, but still not work.

Answer (score 11):

**Reinstall your application and then Run again, It worked for me**

```
CachedNetworkImage(
            placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
            imageUrl: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
          )
```

Comment: Reinstall did the trick.

Answer (score 8):

It works after changing:

```
placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

to:

```
placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

BTW: cached_network_image had a breaking change in 0.6.0.

The tutorial link (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images) is out of date.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add explanation to the above agreed answer.

`placeholder` is of type `Widget Function(BuildContext, String)? placeholder`

So it throws you error:

> The argument type `CircularProgressIndicator` can't be assigned to the parameter type `(BuildContext, String) → Widget`

Convert:

```
placeholder: CircularProgressIndicator()
```

to

```
placeholder: (context, url) => new CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of the package and its required dart sdk version .

link : https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image/versions